# Numerical variables that store logical variable R

Tags: r

A question I have been unable to answer: I need to use the logical variable I created to create two numerical variables: HRate which contains all the Homicide.rate values that are greater than 4.3, and LRate which contains all remaining Homicide.rate values. gunData is a csv file that has values that I attached.

The logical variable code  is:

```
Homicide_index <- ifelse(gunData$Homicide.rate > 4.3, TRUE, FALSE)
```

I'm not sure how to create HRate and LRate based on the question

I tried

```
HRate <- gunData$Homicide.rate[which(Homicide_Index)]
LRate <- gunData$Homicide.rate[which(!Homicide_Index)]
```

But it's obviously wrong. Could someone lend me a hand?

This is in R

Answer (score 0):

You could simply reorder the code to:

```
HRate <- gunData[Homicide_Index,]$Homicide.rate
LRate <- gunData[!Homicide_Index,]$Homicide.rate
```

I would prefer:

```
HRate <- gunData[Homicide_Index,"Homicide.rate"]
LRate <- gunData[!Homicide_Index,"Homicide.rate"]
```

Comment: `Error in `[.data.frame`(gunData, Homicide_Index, ) : object 'Homicide_Index' not found` is what I get

Comment: I simply copied your own code. But it seems your index is defined with small *i* (Homicide_index). Remember R is case sensitive.